# SCP recursive file transfer order

Tags: ssh, scp

Wondering whether it's possible to specify a sort order when transferring files with `scp`.

For example:
`$ scp -r "user@host:/path/to/download/" .`

`[... files download in a seemingly random order ...]`

Since perhaps this may be related to how `scp` functions, is there some way to configure ssh on the source(server)-side so that files are transfered, for example, in ascending filename order?

Answer (score 5):

I whould solve the problem with `tar` and the pipe-transparency of `ssh`. An example can be seen below, the remote PC is named `bar`. Before the test, I created three empty files in `/tmp/foo` by executing `ssh bar 'mkdir /tmp/foo ; touch /tmp/foo/{a,b,c}'`.

```
$ ssh bar 'cd /tmp/foo ; ls | sort -r | tar -cT -' | tar -xv
c
b
a
$ ls -l a b c
-rw-r--r-- 1 dnet dnet 0 nov   29 17:07 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 dnet dnet 0 nov   29 17:07 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 dnet dnet 0 nov   29 17:07 c
```

The `-T` flag of `tar` makes it read filenames to pack from the next parameter, and `-` means the standard input. Now you just need to pipe the name of the files into it, which can come from `ls` (as in the example) or `find` for trickier tasks. With this setup, you can use `sort` to indicate the exact order the files will be transmitted through SSH (in this case, `-r` sorted files in reverse alphabetic order). The `-v` is only added to the final, unpacking `tar`, so that the order is visible.

Comment: Woah, great lower-level approach and presenting the broader picture so clearly. Thank you.

Comment: How could such an approach be extended to transfer files individually instead of in an archive? Would a loop iterating over results from `sort` in the `bar` remote command somehow accomplish this?

Comment: It might, but I don't see the problem with transferring it as an arcive. If you think about it, there's not much difference between this approach and `scp` -- both send metadata and contents for each file, they just use a different "protocol". I guess you could iterate over the results, but then you should take care of files with whitespace in their names.

Comment: @dimadima, if you like the answer so much, perhaps you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: This answer works, but one has to adjust it to the case when files have spaces in names.

Answer (score 3):

One can achieve file transfer with alphabetical order using `rsync`:

```
rsync -P -e ssh -r user@remote_host:/some_path local_path
```

`P` allows partial downloading, `e` sets the SSH protocol and `r` downloads recursively.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, I provided a simple solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067175

Still waiting for a cleverer way to do it!

Comment: This is just a link.  For a complete answer, provide the answer here and then provide the link for reference.